# Get title of child window after it loads fully

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I need to detect changes in the title of a window for OAuth.
I have a link that opens the authentication page in a new window, and I'm just trying to pull the title data. However, for some reason the page doesn't load until all my code executes so the title it finds is just an empty string.

```
$("#signon").on("click", function () {
    var url = $(this).data('authurl');
    var handle = window.open(url);
    var title = window.document.title;
    var title2 = handle.document.title;
});
```

*title* is fine, but *title2* is null and the handle window hasn't loaded.

I've tried .ready, .onload, .load, and an eventListener, but none of them made a difference.

Why isn't the child window loading any data until this code completes?

Comment: This is almost certainly because of the Same-Origin policy.  Are you opening the OAuth window and pointing it at another origin? The minute you do that your code looses access to almost anything that might give you insights into what is going on with the other origin ... including the title.

Comment: That might be the case. According to the OAuth documentation I have however, I'm supposed to be getting the auth code in the title. There must be some way to do it.

Comment: What documentation are you looking at?

Comment: [NetDocuments OAuth Documentation](https://vault.netvoyage.com/neWeb2/delView.aspx?env=%2FQ7%2Fp%2Fd%2Fa%2Fd%2F~130517183523072.nev&dn=1&v=0&dl=1&p=0&e=20140628&t=pE8JUCw4ABEp3Si0dEc7XEnqLkE%3D)

I'm trying to use the redirect_uri _urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob_ (See the last section, Out-Of-Browser Redirect URI)

Comment: That redirect is *only* for non-browser applications that are using an embedded browser component that doesn't reliably notify the parent application about redirects.  It won't work in a web browser.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. In the end, this authorization is going to be accomplished through an embedded browser. I didn't realize that redirect wouldn't work in a browser. The code executes just fine using a different redirect.

Comment: How do I mark a question as closed if no answers were posted?

Comment: There should be a `delete` link at the very bottom :-)